# Are there examples of orthogonal linguistic variables (ling-vars)?

Tags: sociolinguistics

Many ling-vars seemingly (to me, at least) are not:

- race
- gender (certainly NOT binary but countable)
- education level (HS, college, grad school)
- 1st language
- income level (e.g.,above, between, below $x/yr)
- place of birth
- ling feature counts in a speech sample

All thoughts welcome.

Comment: You might have to include some introduction to the concept of "linguistic variables." I just googled it and clearly there's a lot to learn, but it's not clear to me whether it's essentially a feature of linguistics, or of the field of modelling human languages for representation in computing architectures.

Comment: It's not clear that this is a concept unique to English.

Comment: What do you mean by *orthogonal*? The features given in the example are statistical features showing some correlations, but they cannot be orthogonal in the sense of linear algebra. Truly statistically independent features don't exist in sociolinguistics.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 4):

This 99% not a linguistic question, it is a statistical question. Here is as much as I can eke out as a linguistic question. Linguistics is interested in the properties of "language", as manifested in behavior of individuals. You say "boot", I say "trunk", you say "bonnet", I say "hood". I'm from the US, you're from the UK. What causes these differences in behavior is something, but what? You start taking note of other properties that might be associated with that effect, which could include noting age (I'm older than you), race (no idea about you but I'm fairly pale), and the aforementioned "place". We gather up a tone of data and discover that there is a very strong correlation between "place of birth" and "what word you use".

Well, things can get complicated, so if you're looking at a linguistic feature in the US, you mighty find a correlation between the property of language in question, plus the race, place of birth, or income of the speaker. Why is that? Ask a sociologist for details, but race, place of birth and income are not fully independent. Particular income values can, for example, be caused by differences in race. Then you would undertake a sophisticated statistical analysis (if possible) to determine whether it is really *race*, or is it place of birth? Or some compound correlation.

I would be remiss if I didn't point out the probability of indeterminate causation. Does a linguistic property determine income, or does income determine a linguistic property. Both are probably true. I would also be remiss if I didn't point out that statisticians don't talk about causation, they talk about correlation, so don't go asking statistical question about causation. Correlation may be evidence for causation, or not.